# MySQL Selecting wrong column value in Group By query with alias in where clause

Tags: mysql

I know this question was already asked in a similar way, but I could not found any with an alias in the where clause.

I have a table structure like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
( ID int NOT NULL Primary Key
, OrderNr VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
, Date DATE NOT NULL
, Time CHAR(6) NOT NULL
, GeoCode CHAR(6) NULL) ;
```

My insert looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO orders (ID, OrderNr, Date, Time, GeoCode) VALUES (1, '123456', '2022-02- 
15', '111110', '4022')
, (2, '123457', '2022-02-15', '121210', '4022')
, (3, '123455', '2021-04-15', '171515', '4020')
, (4, '123455', '2021-04-16', '150302', '4022')
, (5, '123466', '2022-03-03', '191810', '4020')
, (6, '123466', '2022-03-04', '121410', '4022')
```

Now I´m trying to get the latest Date and Time values for all OrderNr like this:

```
SELECT ID, OrderNr, MAX(cast(concat(Date, ' ', cast(Time as Time)) as datetime)) as 
DateAndTime, GeoCode
FROM Orders o1
GROUP BY OrderNr
```

The Results shows the right latest date and time but the GeoCode is wrong. E.g for the
OrderNr 123455 it is 4020 but should be 4022.

[image]

I know that similar question were already asked but I cant use the alias in the where clause. Can somebody explain to me what I´m doing wrong?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Why is 4022 correct and 4020 incorrect?

Comment: Thank you very much for your question. Because 4020 is not the latest record of the OrderNr 123455. There are 2 entries for the OrderNr 123455 one of the date 2021-04-15 and one of date 2021-04-16. I wanted the latest, this would be 2021-04-16 with the GeoCode 4022.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your mysql version support `ROW_NUMBER` window function you can try this

```
SELECT *
FROM (

    SELECT ID, 
          OrderNr, 
          cast(concat(Date, ' ', cast(Time as Time)) as datetime) DateAndTime, 
          GeoCode,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OrderNr ORDER BY cast(concat(Date, ' ', cast(Time as Time)) as datetime) DESC) rn
    FROM Orders o1
) t1
WHERE rn = 1
```

or use subquery with `EXISTS`

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders o1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Orders oo
    WHERE oo.OrderNr = o1.OrderNr
    HAVING MAX(oo.Date) = o1.Date
)
```

[sqlfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bPY6BLEaooFz3qH6J94apG/0)

Comment: Thank you very much D-Shih. Both solutions work but in the second one what would be if the date is the same and only the time differs? I tried something like this: SELECT * 
FROM Orders o1
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
   FROM Orders oo
   WHERE oo.OrderNr = o1.OrderNr
   HAVING MAX(oo.Date AND oo.Time) = MAX(o1.Date AND o1.Time)
            ) # but it don´t work like expected

Comment: @Efa That depend on your grouping logic could you provide some sample and expect result?

Comment: Sure. For example I would have two more columns. Like: `'7', '123477', '2022-05-15', '121410', '4020'
'8', '123477', '2022-05-15', '151410', '4022'` At this moment HAVING MAX(oo.Date) would show both results the ID 7 and 8 because both Date values are the same. 2022-05-15. (And thank you all that you didn´t down voted me so far)

Comment: @Efa Yes if this example the first solution might be better

Comment: I think so too, thank you very much D-Shih.